# I'm using ExtentSparkReporter for generating extent reports in cucumber with testng ...how to add screenshot for failure scenarios

Tags: testng, cucumber, extent

```java
package cucumberhooks;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.Status;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.gherkin.model.Given;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentSparkReporter;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.configuration.Theme;

import io.cucumber.plugin.EventListener;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.EmbedEvent;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.EventPublisher;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.HookTestStep;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.PickleStepTestStep;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.TestCaseStarted;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.TestRunFinished;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.TestRunStarted;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.TestSourceRead;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.TestStepFinished;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.TestStepStarted;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.WriteEvent;


public class customReportListener implements EventListener {


    private ExtentSparkReporter spark;
    private ExtentReports extent;


    Map<String, ExtentTest> feature = new HashMap<String, ExtentTest>();
    ExtentTest scenario;
    ExtentTest step;


    public customReportListener() {
    };


    @Override
    public void setEventPublisher(EventPublisher publisher) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        /*
         * :: is method reference , so this::collecTag means collectTags method in
         * 'this' instance. Here we says runStarted method accepts or listens to
         * TestRunStarted event type
         */
        publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestRunStarted.class, this::runStarted);
        publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestRunFinished.class, this::runFinished);
        publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestSourceRead.class, this::featureRead);
        publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestCaseStarted.class, this::ScenarioStarted);
        publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestStepStarted.class, this::stepStarted);
        publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestStepFinished.class, this::stepFinished);
        publisher.registerHandlerFor(EmbedEvent.class, this::embedEventhandler);
        publisher.registerHandlerFor(WriteEvent.class, this::writeEventhandler);




    };


    /*
     * Here we set argument type as TestRunStarted if you set anything else then the
     * corresponding register shows error as it doesn't have a listner method that
     * accepts the type specified in TestRunStarted.class
     */


    // Here we create the reporter
    private void runStarted(TestRunStarted event) {
        spark = new ExtentSparkReporter("./Reports/ExtentReportResults.html");
        extent = new ExtentReports();
        spark.config().setTheme(Theme.DARK);
        // Create extent report instance with spark reporter
        extent.attachReporter(spark);
    };


    // TestRunFinished event is triggered when all feature file executions are
    // completed
    private void runFinished(TestRunFinished event) {
        extent.flush();
    };


    // This event is triggered when feature file is read
    // here we create the feature node
    private void featureRead(TestSourceRead event) {
        String featureSource = event.getUri().toString();
        String featureName = featureSource.split(".*/")[1];
        if (feature.get(featureSource) == null) {
        feature.putIfAbsent(featureSource, extent.createTest(featureName));
        }
    };


    // This event is triggered when Test Case is started
    // here we create the scenario node
    private void ScenarioStarted(TestCaseStarted event) {
        String featureName = event.getTestCase().getUri().toString();


        scenario = feature.get(featureName).createNode(event.getTestCase().getName());
    };


    // step started event
    // here we creates the test node
    private void stepStarted(TestStepStarted event) {


        String stepName = " ";
        String keyword = "Triggered the hook :";


        // We checks whether the event is from a hook or step
        if (event.getTestStep() instanceof PickleStepTestStep) {
            // TestStepStarted event implements PickleStepTestStep interface
            // WHich have additional methods to interact with the event object
            // So we have to cast TestCase object to get those methods
            PickleStepTestStep steps = (PickleStepTestStep) event.getTestStep();
            stepName = steps.getStep().getText();
            keyword = steps.getStep().getKeyword();


        } else {
            // Same with HoojTestStep
            HookTestStep hoo = (HookTestStep) event.getTestStep();
            stepName = hoo.getHookType().name();
        }


        step = scenario.createNode(Given.class, keyword + " " + stepName);
    };


    // This is triggered when TestStep is finished
    private void stepFinished(TestStepFinished event) {


        if (event.getResult().getStatus().toString() == "PASSED") {
            step.log(Status.PASS, "This passed");


        } else if (event.getResult().getStatus().toString() == "SKIPPED")


        {


            step.log(Status.SKIP, "This step was skipped ");
        } else {
            step.log(Status.FAIL,"This is failed");
           
        }
    };
    private void embedEventhandler(EmbedEvent embed)
    {
    
    }
    private void writeEventhandler(WriteEvent write)
    {
        
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Register event handle:**

```
    publisher.registerHandlerFor(EmbedEvent.class, this::stepEmbedded);
```

**Catch the event:**

```
private void stepEmbedded(EmbedEvent event) {

        byte[] a = event.getData();
        String s = new String(a);
  
       try {
            step.log(Status.FAIL, "Test Failed" ,
                    MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromBase64String(s).build());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    };
```

**Add the event trigger action to hook:**

```
@AfterStep
    public void endstep(Scenario scenario) {

      //Take screen shot and make a base64 img and attach it to scenario as
TakesScreenshot newScreen = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
String img = newScreen.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BASE64);
            scenario.attach(img, "image/png", "screenshot");
        
    }
```

Comment: Hi, added above code but i'm not able to see screenshot in the report